# optimizar codigo Javascript multiples llamadas asincronas

Tags: javascript, ajax, async

este es mi primera publicación y agradezco mucho me ayuden en mi pequeño problema.
Básicamente la idea es hacer múltiples llamadas a la vez a un link en el menor tiempo posible (entre 20 a 50 peticiones). inicialmente estuve haciendo pruebas con JQuery, sin embargo al usar sus propias funciones para hacerlas mas legibles, hay una ligera perdida en el tiempo de ejecución, por lo menos es lo que leí en algún lado.
Así que decidí hacerlo al viejo estilo, sin usar ningún framework.

```
function loadXMLDoc(url) {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

var Seed = Date.now();
var Srv= document.domain.split('.')[0];
var listaUrl = new Array(20);
var iCnt = 0;
while (iCnt<20) {
  listaUrl[iCnt]='https://' +Srv+ '.darkorbit.com/indexInternal.es?action=internalSkylab&_='+Seed+iCnt; iCnt++;
}

iCnt = 0;
while (iCnt<20) {loadXMLDoc(listaUrl[iCnt]); iCnt++;}
```

EL código que necesito optimizar es la ultima línea, la que hace la llamada por ajax de forma asíncrona al método LoadXMLDoc() y la URL
https://int1.darkorbit.com/indexInternal.es?action=internalSkylab

Saludos cordiales.

Answer (score 0):

El uso de `XMLHttpRequest` está prácticamente obsoleto. Hoy en día se recomienda el uso de [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch).

`fetch` devuelve como resultado una `Promise`, por lo que podemos hacer un paradigma *async*.

```
const seed = Date.now();
const [ srv ] = document.domain.split('.');
// construye la url basado en iCnt
const getUrl = i => `https://${srv}.darkorbit.com/
                    indexInternal.es?action=internalSkylab&_=
                    ${seed}${i}`;


// [...Array(20).keys()] devuelve
// un array de 0 a 19.
const urls = [...Array(20).keys()].map(getUrl);
const requests = urls.map(fetch); // Fetch hace una HTTP request (method GET) por defecto

// Requests es un array de Promise
const all = Promise.all(requests);
// all es una Promise que va a resolverse cuando todas
// las Promise de requests se hayan resuelto.
all.then(results => {
    // results es un array
    // con los resultados de las llamadas HTTP
});
```

Las 20 peticiones HTTP van a hacerse en paralelo y `all` se resolverá cuando todas hayan concluido.
No hace falta esperar a que se resuelva una llamada HTTP para efectuar la siguiente.

El código se puede comprimir un poco con un solo `map` del siguiente modo

```
const fetchFor = i => {
    const url = getUrl(i);
    return fetch(url);
}

const requests = [...Array(20).keys()].map(fetchFor);
Promise.all(requests)
       .then(results => {
            // ...
       });
```

Espero que sirva.